# Framer x cannot find module "framer-motion"

Tags: framer-motion

Apologies in advance for the stupid questions I am a novice.

I am creating a demo in framer x and I am trying to create a custom code component that uses framer motion. I tried installing framer motion using node.js ohmyzsh, npm and framer x still outputs "module named
"framer-motion" not found" I tried changing "framer-motion" to "'framer-motion/dist/framer-motion" and I also tried going into the package.json to change the version to 4.1.17 but still no avail.

I use Mojave 12.0.1, react-motion is nowhere to be found inside the contents of app but is stored in node modules folder in users. Is that the problem?

my component file:

`import {
animate,
motion,
useMotionTemplate,
useMotionValue,
useTransform,
} from "framer-motion"
import { Frame, addPropertyControls, ControlType } from "framer"

// Learn more: https://framer.com/api

export function A(props) {`.....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vTpW.png)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still useful, but I used to work at Framer and this sounds like an outdated client.

What version of Framer are you running? You mention 'framer x', so if you really are on the older Framer X version I'd recommend to update to the latest release (framer.com/desktop). In that version, Motion comes pre-installed and all docs on framer.com/developers should be quite accurate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).